# How to clean my hair without being able to wash it?

Tags: cleaning

I got a wound on my temple stitched up and bandaged. The doctor said I shouldn't let it get wet for a couple of weeks, and also shouldn't wash my hair as it can irritate the wound.

The problem is, my hair gets greasy very quickly, I have to wash it in almost every 3 days. Is there a way to alleviate this problem? I don't want to shave my hair, it's around 20 cm long, but I also don't want to look like a hobo after a few days.

Comment: Since the injury is on your temple, can't you tilt your head so the injury is up and simply wash your hair that way? Gravity would prevent the water from running in it. You should also cover it with something waterproof (just in case).

Comment: Once I wasn't allowed to shower until the wound healed. After a few days I decided I needed to be clean, so I put a plaster on the wound, then covered it with cling film and plenty of tape, then showered as usual. Then I removed the plaster and had a clean body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most effective "dry shampoo" I know of is corn starch.  It works by binding to skin oil on the hair shafts, but not bonding to the hairs or skin (as long as they're dry).  Spread a couple tablespoons of starch evenly through your hair, working it well in with your fingers (almost as if shampooing), then comb/blow the starch out.

It's no substitute for actually washing, but it'll be a lot better than completely letting your hair go for three weeks.

Comment: Check with a doctor before trying this, or any other, remedy!

Answer (score 3):

Wear a hat.

Seriously, if you can't get it wet, you don't want potentially irritating dry chemicals on it either.

Answer (score 2):

Homemade Dry Shampoo Recipe

There are many different substances that you can use as the base of dry shampoo. Ground-up oatmeal, arrowroot powder, and a variety of other fine, absorptive powders can be used. Organic cornstarch is easy to find and it’s something that I always have around the house anyway. Cornstarch absorbs oil, well.

Ingredients

½ cup organic cornstarch

Optional Additions

- 3-4 drops essential oil (for the scent)
- 2 Tbsp unsweetened cocoa powder (for people with darker hair)
- 2 Tbsp cinnamon (for people with red or auburn hair)

Directions

Combine all ingredients well and store your all-natural, homemade dry shampoo in the container of your choice. Some good options are a Mason™ jar with holes poked in the lid, a large un-used salt shaker, or a recycled parmesan cheese container. Mason™ jars can be found in supermarkets, hardware stores, and places where canning supplies are sold. Other brands are Ball, Bernadin, Crown, and others.

Application

Dry shampoo is always applied at the roots of the hair. Use a brush or a comb and separate sections of your hair, shaking the powder onto your scalp. Massage it into the surrounding hair and let it sit for approximately two minutes–just enough time to absorb all that oil! When you’re finished, brush the dry shampoo through your hair until it is no longer visible.

Results

It mostly involves giving up on straight hair forever and embracing your natural curls, but dry shampoo helps a little bit. It can’t replace a regular hair-washing routine, but it does help get an extra day or two when you need it.

For something that’s simple and inexpensive to make, all-natural dry shampoo is very effective!

[Source of article excerpt at DIYNatural.com](http://www.diynatural.com/homemade-dry-shampoo-recipe/)

Disclaimer: check with your medical practitioner regarding suitability of materials and processes given here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to buy or make dry shampoo - I just use a nicely scented talcum powder, sprinkle it on my hands and run my hands through my hair, or apply it lightly with a powder puff, wait a few minutes, then brush it through so it doesn't look grey. But, if you're going to use anything as a dry shampoo, you have to be sure not to get any of it in the wound...

It helps to dry up grease and freshens the hair, but whether you can get away with doing that for two weeks without giving in and washing it, I'm not sure.